# SweetAlert2 form validation does not return

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, sweetalert2

Trying to use SweetAlert2 with a form sending confirmation. But no matter what I try, I can't get it to work.

```
Swal.fire({
  title: err_msg,
  //html: strCEmail,
  text: 'hello',
  type: 'question',
  showCancelButton: true,
  confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
  cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
  confirmButtonText: 'Yes, send it!'
}).then((result) => {
  if (result.value) {
    // xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
  }
});
```

The code reachs the xxxxxxxxxxxxx fine, but whatever I put there doesn't trigger the form to submit.

I've tried the obvious

```
return true;
```

But that didn't work. Then after some digging I found a suggestion to submit the form like this:

```
document.forms["myform"].submit();
```

or
    form.submit();

Which didn't work.

So... what can I use to submit the form once the user has selected submit in SweetAlert2?

Comment: Well it is asynchronous so return is going to do crap. Using submit should work, I guess you should have an error message in console.

Comment: what does your "result" shows if you print it in console?

Comment: Also, try to "fix" your code using the pikachu example from the docs: https://sweetalert.js.org/guides/#advanced-examples

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you're trying to access something that doesn't exist. 
Based on SWAL documentation and this post: [Response from Sweet-alert confirm dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33414259/response-from-sweet-alert-confirm-dialog)
you should just try to do "if(result)" instead of "if(result.value)".

Also, as I commented above, you should go through the documentation and read the pokémon example, it may give you a hint:  sweetalert.js.org/guides/#advanced-examples

Answer (score 0):

Give id to your form

```
<form action="your-action" method="post" id="my_form">
```

In js:

```
Swal.fire({
  title: err_msg,
  text: 'hello',
  type: 'question',
  showCancelButton: true,
  confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
  cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
  confirmButtonText: 'Yes, send it!'
}).then((result) => {
  if (result.value) {
      $(document).find('#my_form').submit();
  }
});
```